# Mockito: How to verify a method was called only once with exact parameters ignoring calls to other methods?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mocking, mockito

Using Mockito in Java how to verify a method was called only once with exact parameters ignoring calls to other methods?

Sample code:

```
public class MockitoTest {

    interface Foo {
        void add(String str);
        void clear();
    }


    @Test
    public void testAddWasCalledOnceWith1IgnoringAllOtherInvocations() throws Exception {
        // given
        Foo foo = Mockito.mock(Foo.class);

        // when
        foo.add("1"); // call to verify
        foo.add("2"); // !!! don't allow any other calls to add()
        foo.clear();  // calls to other methods should be ignored

        // then
        Mockito.verify(foo, Mockito.times(1)).add("1");
        // TODO: don't allow all other invocations with add() 
        //       but ignore all other calls (i.e. the call to clear())
    }

}
```

What should be done in the `TODO: don't allow all other invocations with add()` section?

Already unsuccessfully tried:

1. `verifyNoMoreInteractions(foo);`

Nope. It does not allow calls to other methods like `clear()`.

2. `verify(foo, times(0)).add(any());`

Nope. It does not take into account that we allow one call to `add("1")`.

Comment: How about using [verifyNoMoreInteractions](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/1.10.19/org/mockito/Mockito.html#verifyNoMoreInteractions(java.lang.Object...))?

Comment: then it will say "the call to clear() is not expected" but we want to ignore calls to all methods except add()

Comment: ignore means you want to fail the test case in this case?

Comment: "ignore" means "The test results does not depend on what happend there"

Comment: One way I can think of right now is to change the mock to throw an exception if anything other then "1" is passed as parameter. Edit: below answer is better.

Comment: Nice idea with the exception, but sometimes it is a Spy so you can't change the behaviour.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

```
Mockito.verify(foo, Mockito.times(1)).add("1");
Mockito.verify(foo, Mockito.times(1)).add(Mockito.anyString());
```

The first `verify` checks the expected parametrized call and the second `verify` checks that there was only one call to `add` at all.

Comment: if add method calls 2 or more times, then second line will fail, if add method calls only once with a different argument first line will fail. so this make sure that add method is called once with given argument , but not called with other arguments.

Comment: add this last line to ur code, test will fail. then comment the line  foo.add("1"); . then test will fail. then uncomment it and comment  foo.add("2"); then test will pass. that's what u want right

Comment: You are absolutely right! You will get the checkmark! Thank you!

Comment: Is there no way to set kind of a @Rule for mockito to fail by default if when isn't set for this method?

Comment: It was the second line I didn't understand was checking the total number of calls until I tried it. So the following 3rd line would fail if there was a 3rd call to the method (with any arg) that my test wasn't aware of:   verify(mock, times(1)).method(eq(expectedParam));
  verify(mock, times(1)).method(eq(expectedParam2));
  verify(mock, times(2)).method(any());

Comment: So ensure method isn't called: verify(mock, times(0)).method(any());

Answer (score 42):

The previous answer can be simplified even further.

```
Mockito.verify(foo).add("1");
Mockito.verify(foo).add(Mockito.anyString());
```

The single parameter `verify` method is just an alias to the `times(1)`implementation.

Comment: This simplification does provide value if you are primarily concerned with minimizing character count.  However the accepted Answer has value too, in that it is more explicit as to the times:  It makes it clear 1x times, whereas the code in this answer would only express that via looking at the JavaDoc for #verify.  The accepted Answer would be more immediately clear to a coder who is not familiar with #validate defaults, and might not otherwise have a reason to look at its Javadoc.

Comment: any() should be used when never() is used. verify(x, never()).method(anyString())

Answer (score -1):

```
verify(mock.methodName()).called(1// or any number that u should check);
```